# Why is my dog very weak and having difficulty to move?

Tags: dogs, diseases

My dog has been with us for 14 years. He's not a pure breed but probably around 3 feet long.

I woke him up yesterday to give him some food. And he could not stand up properly to eat the food. He tried his best and his legs were just weak and wobbly until he started panicking and howling but still unable to stand. After 20 mins of eating he calmed down and was able to stand. But he's having a hard time walking and a little wobbly. Is this a nerve issue or muscle issue? Can it be supplemented with vitamins?

Comment: You probably need to get a vet to be sure. It could be anything from old age, to low blood sugar (since he was better after he ate).

Comment: you will have to take your dog to the vet for this,it is not possible to diagnose a dog over the net for anybody and most of us here are common pet owners.(do not start any treatment until you have been to the vet)

Answer (score 1):

Our dog at 14 had a similar issue due to a problem that affected his balance. I don't remember what it was called, but he symptoms sound similar. Of course you should get him to a vet soon for a professional opinion, but it may be a similar problem. When we took our dog into the vet they told us that it would pass after about 3 weeks. He had it much worse and could not walk at all during this time without assistance.

I would rec.
1. Try to get him up and moving as much as you can
2. Don't have him do much rigorous exercise